# Spotlight currency converter not updating

Tags: macos, macos-catalina

Here's the thing:

Currency converter works only once. It stores the current value for a given currency and then it stops updating it.

So if tomorrow said currency goes up 10%, spotlight won't show that—it will still show old prices.

I've noticed that when I restart my mac (macbook pro) it does clean it up and it works again. But then, once again, it doesn't update. So if I want to use it again, I need to shut down my macbook basically every day.

A spotlight rebuild via terminal (sudo mdutil -E /) also doesn't work.

I need to fully restart my macbook, which is a bit counter-productive.

Any ideas on how to solve that?

Thanks in advance!